# browser caching: same remote filename in different sites

Tags: javascript, caching

I have several different sites in different hosts and I use the same JS file in all of them which is loaded from one and only remote host. For instance,

One single JS filename **my.js** is stored at **someotherhost.net**.

This filename is loaded in several different pages (sites):
**somedomain1.net/home.html**
**somedomain2.net/home.html**
**somedomain3.net/home.html**

Browsing through these sites browser caches **my.js**. But will it use the *same cache* for all different sites?

Or maybe it doesn't matter whether the requested filename is named the same, stored in single remote host and loaded in different pages, browser will have different caches?

How browser caching works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The browser will cache each unique url, provided there are no [headers](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/http-headers-for-dummies/) that tell it not to.

Your file should have one entry in the browser cache even if it is requested from a number of referring pages. Once cached from one site the browser will use the cached version for all the others so speeding up the page load.

This is the idea behind loading JavaScript libraries from a CDN (content delivery network). If you load jquery from `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js` there's a <strike>good</strike> chance the user already has it in their browser cache so it will load instantly.